# How to see the author of a Facebook's page post?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

Facebook allows for groups of people to be page administrators, and then post in this page with the page profile. If one of them posts in a page's timeline with the page profile, can I see who's the original author if I'm also an administrator?

Comment: No. That's not supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, just updating that now there's a very useful [activity log](https://www.facebook.com/help/www/364839563545997) for pages.

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot see the who is the author of your post when using Facebook Pages under multiple admins. Consider looking into a third party tool to manage tracking roles.

Comment: Any suggestion of tool to do that?

Comment: @ViniciusMassuchetto Maybe Hootsuite